# Time Difference between two time columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, time

I have the issue in getting the minutes difference between two time columns in sql server.

```
Column1: Starttime
Column2: Endtime
```

These two are of the type `nchar(10)` , I converted them into time format in the below way and using the datediff function.
If the two columns have AM format or PM format, then difference of minutes is coming fine. But if i have start time is in PM format and End time as AM (SQL taking it as next day) format then i am getting negative minutes than expected.

```
select 
    dty_act_start_time,
    dty_act_end_time,
    datediff(minute, convert(varchar,dty_act_start_time,114),convert(varchar,dty_act_end_time,114)) 
from DB.Mydatabase;
```

Please let me know how to get the correct difference in minutes.

Comment: Those aren't time columns, they are strings with unknown contents. Nothing ensures the fields actually contain english-style AM/PM time strings. If you want to store time use the *correct* type, ie `time` or `datetime` etc.

Comment: Unless you provide sample data and desired results, we can only guess.

Comment: _`I converted them into time format`._  This is plainly false. You converted them from one string type to another string type. SQL databases have datetime and time types for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add 1440 minutes (number of minutes in 24 hours) if start time is greater than end time:

```
select
    start_time_time,
    end_time_time,
    datediff(minute, start_time_time, end_time_time) + iif(start_time_time <= end_time_time, 0, 1440) as diff
from (
    select
    convert(time(0), dty_act_start_time, 114) as start_time_time,
    convert(time(0), dty_act_end_time, 114) as end_time_time
    from (values
        ('09:00am', '10:00pm'),
        ('10:00pm', '09:00am')
    ) tests(dty_act_start_time, dty_act_end_time)
) x
```

Result:

```
start_time_time | end_time_time | diff
09:00:00        | 22:00:00      | 780
22:00:00        | 09:00:00      | 660
```

Comment: This likely works to user needs (assuming 1 day difference always); but others need to be aware that if multiple days are involved, this doesn't fit the bill; but as there is only time listed in the question some assumptions must be made.

Comment: @xQbert if OP were using datetime then there would be no ambiguity at all. 01:00 of 2000-01-03 is greater than 23:00 of 2000-01-01.

Comment: Agreed.  the issue i've seen with times in the past in has been that it's greater than a 24 hour period difference.  And then, they want to know how may days were involved...  which just can't be done.  That may/may not be the case here.  But if you have both time & date then the difference is very easy to determine.